# ERROR on -$ dotcloud run myapp.www python current/myapp/manage.py syncdb

Tags: django, dotcloud

Django noob. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong here? I looked this up on google, and the closest issue I found was [this](http://answers.dotcloud.com/question/86/django-can-not-use-managepy) and [this](http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=dotcloud%20manage.py%20syncdb%20error&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#pq=dotcloud%20manage.py%20syncdb%20error&hl=en&sugexp=kjrmc&cp=29&gs_id=6&xhr=t&q=1045%20access%20denied%20for%20user&qe=MTA0NSwgIkFjY2VzcyBkZW5pZWQgZm9yIHVzZXI&qesig=VxJWd46YpJF_ZpnQMjZ9xA&pkc=AFgZ2tmLYUVnWdZB-vAFIm_nPThU1AsoQyWzAePHWwNcnOB99lujxU9IKOElJDtRGiiCNogCmfd91XEIRjhL22s8i6o6DoUDVQ&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&client=ubuntu&hs=0tp&channel=fs&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=1045,%20%22Access%20denied%20for%20user&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=f&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=dc20b2672385f007&biw=1253&bih=819) -- but couldn't figure it out.

Is this a password issue? I have the mysql password on my settings.py

I appreciate your help.

```
j@ime:~/dotcloud$ dotcloud run jims.www python current/jims/manage.py syncdb
# python current/jims/manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "current/jims/manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/home/dotcloud/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/dotcloud/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/dotcloud/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/dotcloud/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 219, in execute
    self.validate()
  File "/home/dotcloud/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 249, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/home/dotcloud/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 102, in get_validation_errors
    connection.validation.validate_field(e, opts, f)
  File "/home/dotcloud/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 14, in validate_field
    db_version = self.connection.get_server_version()
  File "/home/dotcloud/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 338, in get_server_version
    self.cursor()
  File "/home/dotcloud/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 250, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/home/dotcloud/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 322, in _cursor
    self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/home/dotcloud/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dotcloud/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'jims'@'ip-10-68-47-216.ec2.internal' (using password: YES)")
Abort.
```

Comment: Check your credentials with `psql -h settings_hostname -d settings_name -U settings_user -W`

Comment: It looks like you are using MySQL; did you create the "jims" user?

Comment: Jim, did you ever figure this out? if so, can you post the solution for future people to learn from.